How was the length of the damper calculated in this figure?

I was reading this research and tried to calculate the length of the damper but couldn't figure out how. tried using the Law of Cosines but ended up with a different result.

Unless you know something I don't then there is not enough information in the diagram to calculate L_d

b is the distance between the knee center and the location of the damper attachment on the shank, s is clear in the figure, distance between the knee center and  the location of the damper attachment on the thigh. theta_s and theta_t are the shank and thigh angles. all the parametres are known except for L_d

I suggest you modify the diagram to get rid of the other b and add b to the first diagram

you are right.
Lets call the second point at the center of the red circle E and the point of intersection of it with ld, F. so $ \ EF = a_2$
Using the law of cosines and recognizing that the angle between the two sides is$\ 90 - \theta_ k$ or $\ 90 - \theta_t - \theta_s$
$$ld^2 = S^2 +a_2^2 - 2 S a_2 \ cos(90- \theta_t - \theta_s) $$
so
$$ld = \sqrt{S^2 +a_2^2 - 2 S a_2 \ cos(90- \theta_t - \theta_s)}$$
Edit
After OP comment
yes:
if you look at the diagram the $cos(\theta_t)$ is positive, but $cos(\theta_s)$ is negative. and we know two complementary angles have
$$sin\alpha= \pm cos (90-\alpha)= \pm sin(\theta_s- \theta_t)= sin(\theta_s-\theta_t)$$
I skipped a couple of steps. I am confident you know it.
I guess this format would be more convenient for authors' future calculations.

a_2 is in the center of l_2
b is where the green link and the damper intersect
so I_d=sqrt(s^2+b^2-2sbcos(90-theta_t-theta_s))
is there any way to reach the "+2bssin(...)" that the author ended up with?

@AbuAhmad, edited the answer, to address your comment. please check.
